# Influence what subpage or subdomain gets on the first spot in Google

Tags: search-engine

We have a website for a product (let's call it "ourproduct") that's on ourproduct.com. We also have an en.ourproduct.com for the English version of the site (the basic version is in Slovenian).

When you search Google for ourproduct, the English subdomain is the first of the results, but we would like the one without the subdomain to be the first, since it's the main one.
The content on both sites is the same, just a different translation, so the keyword ourproduct is on both sites equally represented. The second problem is that the second result is for ourproduct.com/gallery, but I would like our home page to be there.

Is there a way I can influence that or "fix" this?

Comment: Is this really what you want?  This would imply that most people are going to your English site.  Are you hoping to sell worldwide, or is your main market in Slovenia?

Comment: Our main market is in Slovenia, but I see where you're going with this. I will rethink...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the the results the same for Google.com and your local Google (google.si(?)) ? google.com will give preference to English content.

To answer your question there are a couple ways to influence this. Set up webmaster tools for your site ( I think you will need to add each sub-domain separately). There you will be able to set target countries for each sub-domain.

As for /gallery vs your index page, you can submit a sitemap and set the relative importance of the index url higher than that of gallery.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183668&topic=8476&ctx=topic